# Using Applescript to remove text from file

Tags: applescript

i have a code to write input strings to /etc/hosts

```
#Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

# Start List
173.252.100.26  abc.com
173.252.100.26  xyz.com
# End List
```

but i dont know how to write another applescript to find 'Start List' and 'End List' to remove all of contents in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be run with something like `sudo osascript Untitled.scpt`. It doesn't remove linefeeds before or after the strings.

```
set f to POSIX file "/etc/hosts"
set input to read f as «class utf8»
set o1 to offset of "# Start List" in input
set o2 to (offset of "# End List" in input) + 10
if o1 is 0 or o2 is 0 or o1 > o2 then return
if o1 is 1 then
    set s to ""
else
    set s to text 1 thru (o1 - 1) of input
end if
if (o2 - 1) is length of input then
    set e to ""
else
    set e to text o2 thru -1 of input
end if
{s, e}
set output to result as text
set b to open for access f with write permission
set eof b to 0
write output to b as «class utf8»
close access b
```

Or just use sed:

```
sudo sed -i '' '/^# Start List$/,/^# End List$/d' /etc/hosts
```